# How to check when system went on battery power

Tags: boot, power-management, battery, logs

Ubuntu 18.04.

Does anybody know if there is a way to check when the system went on battery power?

It seems my laptop lost power at some point, went to battery power and died (disabled sleep/suspend etc). I can see that it booted back up with the `journalctl --list-boots` command but I am not sure how to pin point when/if it went to battery.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked in syslog and can identify the gap, but that would only tell me when the laptop finally ran out of battery and when it regained AC power to boot back up. I am after the time when the AC power went off and the laptop started discharging from the battery.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vim /var/log/syslog
```

That should give you a pretty good idea.  If it happened some time ago, it may be in syslog.1 or syslog.2.  If it happened a relatively long time ago, you'll have to hunt through the syslong.*n*.gz files.

EDIT: You're looking for a time gap.  As a bonus, you may get a critical power message at the beginning of that gap, in which case you'll know what to look for in the future...  A fancier solution may be writing a PERL or Python script to go through all these files and look automatically.  That amount of effort would be justified if this is something you anticipate happening often.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked in syslog and can identify the gap, but that would only tell me when the laptop finally ran out of battery and when it regained AC power to boot back up. I am after the time when the AC power went off and the laptop started discharging from the battery..